# What does `**` mean in the expression `dict(d1, **d2)`?

Tags: python, syntax, dictionary, operators, set-operations

I am intrigued by the following python expression:

```
d3 = dict(d1, **d2)
```

The task is to merge 2 dictionaries into a third one, and the above expression accomplishes the task just fine. I am interested in the ** operator and what exactly is it doing to the expression. I thought that ** was the power operator and haven't seen it used in the context above yet.

The full snippet of code is this:

```
>>> d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> d2 = {'c': 3, 'd': 4}
>>> d3 = dict(d1, **d2)
>>> print d3
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
```

Comment: It should be noted that GvR thinks this expression is [despicable](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-April/099459.html)

Comment: This only works if the keys in `d2` are strings, at least in Python 3.

Comment: Oh, cool, I didn't realise it would work at all in Python 2. I suppose that's the advantage of `dict(d1, **d2)` over `dict(**d1, **d2)` or `{d1, **d2}` or `{**d1, **d2}`—it works in Python 2. I think that last one is the preferred syntax in Python 3, because it's concise and consistent. But it's nice to know there's a way to do it in Python 2, at least with string keys, even if it does look a bit hackish.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`**` in argument lists has a special meaning, as covered in [section 4.7 of the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions). The dictionary (or dictionary-like) object passed with `**kwargs` is expanded into keyword arguments to the callable, much like `*args` is expanded into separate positional arguments.

Comment: My question is, why use `dict(d1, **d2)` and not `dict(**d1, **d2)`. The latter looks cleaner to me, and the end result seems to be the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: Never mind; I didn't realise we were talking about Python 2, where `dict(d1, **d2)` seems to be the only way. Nice to know it's even possible. I think `{**d1, **d2}` is the preferred syntax in Python 3, though, since it's consistent and concise.

Answer (score 18):

The ** turns the dictionary into keyword parameters:

```
>>> d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> d2 = {'c': 3, 'd': 4}
>>> d3 = dict(d1, **d2)
```

Becomes:

```
>>> d3 = dict(d1, c=3, d=4)
```

Comment: it becomes `dict(d1, c=3, d=4)` instead.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I knew what I meant to type, but my fingers didn't get the message...

Answer (score 11):

In Python, any function can accept multiple arguments with *;
or multiple [**keyword arguments**](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) with **.

Receiving-side example:

```
>>> def fn(**kwargs):
...   for kwarg in kwargs:
...     print kwarg
... 
>>> fn(a=1,b=2,c=3)
a
c
b
```

Calling-side example (thanks Thomas):

```
>>> mydict = dict(a=1,b=2,c=3)
>>> fn(**mydict)
a
c
b
```

Comment: Note that that demonstrates the receiving side, not the calling side.

Answer (score 3):

It's also worth mentioning the mechanics of the dict constructor. It takes an initial dictionary as its first argument and can also take keyword arguments, each representing a new member to add to the newly created dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

you have got your answer of the ** operator. here's another way to add dictionaries

```
>>> d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> d2 = {'c': 3, 'd': 4}
>>> d3=d1.copy()
>>> d3.update(d2)
>>> d3
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

That operator is used to unpack argument list:
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists