# Union of dict objects in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, associative-array, idioms, set-operations

How do you calculate the union of two `dict` objects in Python, where a `(key, value)` pair is present in the result iff `key` is `in` either dict (unless there are duplicates)?

For example, the union of `{'a' : 0, 'b' : 1}` and `{'c' : 2}` is `{'a' : 0, 'b' : 1, 'c' : 2}`.

Preferably you can do this without modifying either input `dict`. Example of where this is useful: [Get a dict of all variables currently in scope and their values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041639/get-a-dict-of-all-variables-currently-in-scope-and-their-values)

Comment: @RikPoggi: The other question, despite its title, is asking about what the `**d2` *syntax* is. It happens to provide an answer to this question.

Comment: `merged_dict = {**dict1, **dict2}` in python 3.5+ (to save you a trip to the other link or from using the buggy solution accepted here which fails if your keys aren't strings).

Comment: `merged_dict = dict(**a,**b,**c,**d)` worked for me too

Comment: Looks like the correct solution will come in Python 3.9, see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/

Comment: Python 3.9 : `a = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}; b = {4: 'd', 5: 'e'}; c = a | b`

Comment: do `{**d1, **d2}`. For details see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python

Answer (score 171, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255878/merging-dictionaries-in-python) provides an idiom. You use one of the dicts as keyword arguments to the `dict()` constructor:

```
dict(y, **x)
```

Duplicates are resolved in favor of the value in `x`; for example

```
dict({'a' : 'y[a]'}, **{'a', 'x[a]'}) == {'a' : 'x[a]'}
```

Comment: "Simple is better than complex." :) You should use `update` member function of `dict`.

Comment: How is `tmp = dict(y); tmp.update(x); do_something(tmp)` simpler?

Comment: @shahjapan This is not complex, this is great use of Python dict structure. And this is different from update (this solution is not updating anything).

Comment: @lajarre: I agree, As in this case OP doesn't want to update any of the dicts - its a nice way to create a new `dict` based on existing dicts.

Comment: It is not 'nice', it is cryptic, and it immediately makes most readers balk and the remainder assume all the keys in x would have to be legal parameter names.  IMHO, the fact it works is a bug in the name-checking mechanisms in the implementation.  What happens when you rely on bugs?  They either get fixed, or become political footballs in the PEP process.

Comment: @JonJayObermark: Agree. `dict(x=2)` is ok but `dict(4=2)` is not. So if `x={4:2}` the proposed method will fail.

Comment: `{**y, **x}` is less verbose, accepts any kinds of keys and works faster than the solution with a temporary dict.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail You say that duplicates are resolved in favor of the value in `x`. Can this idiom be slightly modified to also retain keys in `y` that are missing in `x`? Because currently they get ignored.

Comment: does the order of `dict(y, **x)` vs `dict(**y, x)` matter?

Comment: Great answer ! There is just a small typo : "**{'a', 'x[a]'}" should be "**{'a': 'x[a]'}" i.e. replace the comma by a colon.

Comment: This answer is outdated and will sometimes fail in Python 3. Please don't waste time like I did and look at the canonical answer in the duplicate question instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python

Comment: do `{**d1, **d2}`. For details see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python

Comment: @Ismael ELATIFI is right, `{"a", "x[a]"}` is equivalent to `set(tuple("a", "x[a]"))` I believe.

Comment: Oh dear now I've introduced another error, and stack overflow won't let me edit my comment anymore. It shouldn't be `tuple("a", "x[a]")`, it should just be parenthesized `("a", "x[a]")` since `tuple()` itself takes an iterable as its argument. So `{"a", "x[a]"} == set(("a", "x[a]"))`.

Comment: why does this fail? `            self.indices_to_labels = dict(**self.labels_to_indices, **global_label2global_indices)
`

Answer (score 126):

You can also use [`update`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method of dict like

```
a = {'a' : 0, 'b' : 1}
b = {'c' : 2}

a.update(b)
print a
```

Comment: Note that  `.update` changes `a`. Sometimes, it's inacceptable

Comment: do `{**d1, **d2}`. For details see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python

Comment: why does this fail? `            self.indices_to_labels = dict(**self.labels_to_indices, **global_label2global_indices)
`

Answer (score 71):

**For a static dictionary, combining snapshots of other dicts:**

As of Python 3.9, the binary "or" operator `|` has been defined to concatenate dictionaries. (A new, concrete dictionary is eagerly created):

```
>>> a = {"a":1}
>>> b = {"b":2}
>>> a|b
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Conversely, the `|=` augmented assignment has been implemented to mean the same as calling the `update` method:

```
>>> a = {"a":1}
>>> a |= {"b": 2}
>>> a
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

For details, check [PEP-584](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/)

Prior to Python 3.9, the simpler way to create a new dictionary is to create a new dictionary using the "star expansion" to add teh contents of each subctionary in place:

```
c = {**a, **b}
```

**For dynamic dictionary combination, working as  "view" to combined, live dicts:**

If you need both dicts to remain independent, and updatable, you can create a single object that queries both dictionaries in its `__getitem__` method (and implement  `get`, `__contains__` and other mapping method as you need them).

A minimalist example could be like this:

```
class UDict(object):
   def __init__(self, d1, d2):
       self.d1, self.d2 = d1, d2
   def __getitem__(self, item):
       if item in self.d1:
           return self.d1[item]
       return self.d2[item]
```

And it works:

```
>>> a = UDict({1:1}, {2:2})
>>> a[2]
2
>>> a[1]
1
>>> a[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in __getitem__
KeyError: 3
>>>
```

**NB**: If one wants to lazily maintain a Union "view" of two
or more dictionaries, check  [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) in the standard library - as it has all dictionary methods and cover corner cases not
contemplated in the example above.

Comment: do `{**d1, **d2}`. For details see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python

Comment: sorry @neuron - your edit broke the answer. The second part is not **only** to older versions, it describes how to create a custom mapping which can reference independent sub-dictionaries, and this has nothing to do with the language version. 
(I should come back in a few minutes and fix it back, but please, watch out for the meaning of the text/code when editing)

Comment: why does this fail? `            self.indices_to_labels = dict(**self.labels_to_indices, **global_label2global_indices)
`

Answer (score 38):

**Two dictionaries**

```
def union2(dict1, dict2):
    return dict(list(dict1.items()) + list(dict2.items()))
```

***n* dictionaries**

```
def union(*dicts):
    return dict(itertools.chain.from_iterable(dct.items() for dct in dicts))
```

Comment: Or much more readably, `dict(i for dct in dicts for i in dct.items())`

Comment: Why converting to list() ?
`def union2(dict1, dict2):` `return dict(dict1.items() + dict2.items())`

Comment: @kinORnirvana In python 3:  a = {'x': 1}; type(a.items()) => <class 'dict_items'>

Comment: @kinORnirvana "Why converting to list() ?" Because otherwise: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'dict_items'".

Comment: do `{**d1, **d2}`. For details see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python