# How to find a root of a dynamic function based in columns of a dataset using Python

Tags: python, r, dataset, root, solver

I'm beginner in python and I need to translate some code in R to Python.

I need to find one root per row in a dataset based in a dynamic function, the code in R is:

```
library(rootSolve
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)

 dataset = data.frame(A = c(10,20,30),B=c(20,10,40), FX = c("A+B-x","A-B+x","A*B-x"))

 sol<- adply(dataset,1, summarize,
               solution_0= uniroot.all(function(x)(eval(parse(text=as.character(FX),dataset))),lower = -10000, upper = 10000, tol = 0.00001))
```

This code return [30,-10,1200] as a solution for each row.

In python I read a documentation of optimize of sciPy package but i don't found a code that's work for me:

I tried a solutions like that below, but without sucess:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import fsolve as fs

data = {'A': [10,20,30],
        'B': [20,10,40],
        'FX': ["A+B-x","A-B+x","A*B-x"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def func(FX):
    return(exec(FX))

fs(func(df.FX),x0=0,args=df)
```

Someone have idea how to solve this?

Very Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html) is a symbolic math library for Python. Your question can be solved as:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sympy import Symbol, solve
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

data = {'A': [10,20,30],
        'B': [20,10,40],
        'FX': ["A+B-x","A-B+x","A*B-x"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

x = Symbol("x", real=True)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    F = parse_expr(row['FX'], local_dict={'A': row['A'], 'B': row['B'], 'x':x})
    print (row['A'], row['B'], row['FX'], "-->", F, "-->", solve(F, x))
```

This outputs:

```
10 20 A+B-x --> 30 - x --> [30]
20 10 A-B+x --> x + 10 --> [-10]
30 40 A*B-x --> 1200 - x --> [1200]
```

Note that SymPy's solve returns a list of solutions. If you are sure there is always exactly one solution, just use `solve(F, x)[0]`. (Remember that unlike R, Python always starts indexing with 0.)

With list comprehension, you could write the solution as:

```py
sol = [ solve(parse_expr(row['FX'], local_dict={'A': row['A'], 'B': row['B'], 'x':x}),
              x)[0] for _, row in df.iterrows() ]
```

If you have many columns, you can also create the dictionary with a loop: `dict({c:row[c] for c in df.columns}, **{'x':x}) )`. The weird `**` syntax is needed if you want to combine the dictionaries inside the list comprehension. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819602/union-of-dict-objects-in-python) about the union of dictionaries.

```py
cols = df.columns # change this if you won't need all columns
sol = [ solve(parse_expr(row['FX'],
                         local_dict=dict({c:row[c] for c in cols}, **{'x':x}) ),
              x)[0].evalf() for _, row in df.iterrows() ]
```

PS: SymPy normally keeps the solutions in a symbolic form because it prefers exact expressions. When there are e.g. fractions or square roots, they are not evaluated immediately. To get the evaluated form, use `evalf()` as in `solve(F, x)[0].evalf()`.

Comment: Thanks, another question, is it necessary to create the dictionary for all columns? can i do something like R's "Attached" function? because my dataset has hundreds of columns and this dictionary would be quite large. Thank you again.

Comment: As each row needs its own values for the variables, you'll need to create (or update) the dictionary for each of the rows. If you know some rows only use a subset of the columns, you might restrict the dictionary to only these columns. Anyway, creating the dictionary is not the slowest part of the solution.