# Adding a column to dictReader without modifying the CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file that has 3 columns. Let's say: `a`, `b`, `c`. I'm using `csv.dictReader` to read it and add another column that has just the name of the file on each row.

This is my function:

```
def addFilename(self):
    with open(self.datafile, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='|')
        for a, b, c in reader:
            #Get filename
            filename = self.getFilename()
            yield {
                "_source": {
                    "a": a,
                    "b": b,
                    "c": c,
                    "filename": filename
                }
            }
```

Now I'd like to generalize that behavior for many different CSV files. Those files have different number of columns and different column names. Is there a way to do so?

I don't want to modify the CSV file. The only thing I know is that I can get the fieldnames (and the number of fields) using `reader.fieldnames`, but I don't know how I could use that in a `yield`.

Answer (score 2):

This question may provide some useful insights:

- [What does `**` mean in the expression `dict(d1, **d2)`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2255878/1025391)

Essentially you could do something like this:

```
def foo(fname):
    with open(fname, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='|')
        for row in reader:
            yield { "_source": dict(filename=fname, **row) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to iterate on the level of column names. You can treat all of the existing column values returned by `for ... in reader` as a tuple. Then:

```
   def addFilename2(self):
    with open(self.datafile, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='|')
        for column_dict in reader:
            #Get filename
            filename = self.getFilename()
            mapped_values =list(column_dict.items())
            mapped_values.append(("filename", filename,))
            yield {
                "_source": dict(mapped_values)
                }
```

This approach is oblivious to the names and number of columns in your CSV  file and will always add `filename` as the last column.

Dictionary can be created from a list of 2-tuples which we create based on the column names and values from a particular row using `zip`. Having a list we can append the repeated `filename` and call dictionary constructor so that we can return a dictionary with the additional column.