# How to compare two lists using dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make an easy beggar my neighbour game using Python.

I've two lists named *p1* and *p2* which both have random elements like `['A', 'K', '9', '2']` etc...

I've also a dictionary named *cards_values* with keys and values like: `{'A': 13, 'K': 12}` etc...

...and now I want to compare these two lists using a dictionary to check which player won the round

I'm not gonna paste the code 'cause I want a hint/advice, not the solution.

Comment: this seems like a simple task if you understand how to use dicts/lists, where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Sadly, we're not here to give you hint/advice, we're here to provide solutions, to code that's not working. Please consider reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Look into the `**x` (2nd) argument of the `dict` constructor.

**Answer**: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9819617/7595191) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2255878/7595191) for the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not gonna paste the code 'cause I want a hint/advice, not the solution.

Okay.

So you basically need to get all cards' values for each player, right?

1. Do you know how to get one card's value?
2. All cards for one player = p1 or p2. All cards' values for one player = for each card do the thing you did above. And sum it.

---

Code hints/answers below.

---

1. `cards_values['A']`
2. For loop:

```
sum_p1 = 0
for card in p1:
    sum_p1 += cards_values[card]
```