What does adding ** do?
I want to add 2 dictionaries together to a 3rd dictionary in python, but using d3 = dict(d1,d2) returns an error because it expected one argument but got 2. I looked it up online and saw that d3 = dict(d1,**d2) fixes this. What does the ** do?
d1 = {1:one,2:two}
d2 = {3:three,4:four}

I tried:
d3 = dict(d1,d2)

to add the dictionaries together which gave an error. I then tried:
d3 = dict(d1,**d2)

which worked fine. What did the ** change?

The '**' expands the dictionary into individual key=value pairs for parameters.  A better plan for doing this operation is d1.update(d2).

Python is very well documented. What did you find when reading the documentation?

@TimRoberts: If you're making a new dict, like the OP is, d3 = {**d1, **d2} (since 3.5), or d3 = d1 | d2 (since 3.9) are the way to go.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255878/what-does-mean-in-the-expression-dictd1-d2

The Python documentation for dict() will tell us everything we have to know.
** notation in python, is called kwarg (for keyword argument). So by calling **d2 in a function signature you're specifying Python's unpacking operator for dictionaries and are matching a valid constructor for dictionaries. In other words: **d2 means "take all additional named arguments to this function and insert them into this parameter as dictionary entries.". Look here for more examples of **dictionary and what it means in different use-cases
Note that dict(d1, d2) doesn't work as you can't construct a dictionary with two mapping types in python. But (as pointed out by @phihag), dict(**d1, **d2) will work as multiple kwargs args are supported.
TLDR: Answer resides in the documentation and type supporting :)

dict(**d1, **d2) does work; try it in your Python console. Multiple **  kwargs arguments can be given in a function call.

@phihag: That said, it's not technically guaranteed supported last I checked (unless d1 and d2 are both string-keyed, because functions aren't strictly required to accept arbitrary keyword arguments that aren't legal variable names). {**d1, **d2} and d1 | d2 are both guaranteed to work with arbitrary dictionaries.

@phihag, thanks for the catch-- fixed.

The dict constructor does not take two position arguments, therefore dict(d1, d2) is a type error.
** passes the values of the dictionary as keyword arguments. The dict constructor allows passing in a dictionary (or iterable) and keyword arguments.
If d2 is {"three": 3, "four": 4}, then dict(d1, **d2) is the same thing as dict(d1, three=3, four=4).
To combine two dicts, this is all extremely complicated. Much easier is simply
d1 | d2

