# add new elements to a dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I would like to convert stuff from my csv.reader to a dictionary. I implemented the instructions from this post  [Add new keys to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/add-to-a-dictionary-in-python) but I keep getting `IndexError: list index out of range`. How can I fix this?

```
import wx
import csv

info = csv.reader(open('report.csv', 'rb'),delimiter=',')

length = 0
info_list = []

for row in info: #search each row in the report
    info_list.append([length,row[1],row[4]])
    length = length + 1

print length
dict_info = {}
rows = 0
counter = 0

while counter < length:
    for item in info_list:
        dict_info[item[rows]] = [item[rows + 1], item[rows + 2]]
    rows = rows + 3
    counter = counter + 1
print dict_info
```

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to achieve in a paragraph?

Comment: You are overrunning the bounds of the second `item` you iterate over, which is a list, because each iteration of the `while` loop adds 3 to the `row` value you are indexing in to `item` with, but `item` is only 3 elements long (since you created it as such while looping through `info`).  You're getting an index error on the list; the dict isn't having a problem.  I second @JonClements though in wanting to know what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for index, row in enumerate(info):
    dict_info[index] = [row[1], row[4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

import collections

d = collections.OrderedDict()

info = csv.reader(open('report.csv', 'rb'),delimiter=',')

d = {row[0]:row[1].strip() for row in info}

for some1, some2 in d.items():

and than write everything else

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is:

```
import csv

info = csv.reader(open('report.csv', 'rb'),delimiter=',')
dict_info = {row[0]:[row[1], row[4]] for row in info}
print dict_info
```

If you want the indexes to be the line number if the file, then you should probably just keep it as a list.

```
import csv

info = csv.reader(open('report.csv', 'rb'),delimiter=',')
list_info = [[row[1], row[4]] for row in info]
print list_info
```