# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when calling code from script, but no error when same code is run by creating function in console

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python and am having troubles understanding certain errors. When I run the below code by calling a script which has the function, i get an error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

**But when i create a function in the console and run it, i get no error. Would appreciate your help.**

*The code is*

```
def BookSent(sent_token):
    dictBook = {}
    listBooks = ['st']
    for i in sent_token:
        if re.search(r'Book of [a-zA-Z]+', i) is not None:
            book = re.findall(r'Book of [a-zA-Z]+', i)[0]
            book = str(book)
            if dictBook.has_key(book):
                dictBook[book].append(i)
            else:
                dictBook[book] = []
                dictBook[book].append(i)
                listBooks.append(book)
        else:
            dictBook[listBooks[-1]].append(i)
    return dictBook
```

I have taken care to parse the list item as string before using it as a key, so I do not see why this should be giving an error.

*Complete error message:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\faisal.sayed\Documents\ProjectsPython\textAnalytics.py", line 18, in textBookVerse
    if dictBook.has_key(book):
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: can u give test input for function i.e. value for sent_token?

Comment: Also, it usually helps to post the full traceback (the error message starting from the `Traceback` line), so everyone can see where the error is actually happening.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I have added the complete error message.

Answer (score 1):

Code will give exception on following line when code goes in `else` loop of first if and `dictBook` not contain `st` as key.
 **Exception: KeyError: 'st'**

```
dictBook[listBooks[-1]].append(i)
```

define dictBook as

```
dictBook = {"st":[]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I tried commenting the else, but the error still persists.

I have added the complete traceback error.

Answer (score 0):

import re

def BookSent(sent_token):

```
dictBook = {}

listBooks = ['st']

for i in sent_token:
    if re.search(r'Book of [a-zA-Z]+', i) is not None:
        book = re.findall(r'Book of [a-zA-Z]+', i)[0]
        book = str(book)
        if dictBook.has_key(book):
            dictBook[book].append(i)
        else:
            dictBook[book] = []
            dictBook[book].append(i)
            listBooks.append(book)
    else:
            dictBook.setdefault(listBooks[-1], []).append(i)
return dictBook
```

print BookSent("Book of World")

Comment: did you say this code worked for you? 

if I do the same thing you did, which is to write this code in console and then run the function with a tokenized sentence as input, it works just fine for me. 

But when I write the same function in a script and call the script, I get an error. The way I cal the funciton is
from script import BookSent
b = BookSent(tokenized_sentence)

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your responses. The code was fine. I just put it into another script and it just worked fine. I'm not sure if there was some caching issue or not.

Closing topic.

Answer (score -2):

dictionaries do not have an append method.

You can add by doing this

> dictBook[newKey] = value
>
> or
>
> dictBook.update(key,value)

See [Add new keys to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/add-to-a-dictionary-in-python) for more info.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `append` is being called on `dictBook[book]`, which is a value from the dictionary, in this context always a `list`. Additionally, the mistake you describe would lead to a very different exception than the one in the question.