# Python: Unable to add a new key:value to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am making a dictionary for storing tests and their grades for different students.

```
def tests():
    test1 = {'craig':88, 'jeanie':100}
    test2 = {'craig':85, 'jeanie':95}
    test3 = {'craig':80, 'jeanie':98}
    return test1,test2,test3
def actions(test1,test2,test3):
    test1.update({'john':95})
    test1.update({'chris':92})
    test1.update({'charles',100})
    test2.update({'john':100})
    test2.update({'chris':96})
    test2.update({'charles',98})
    test3.update({'john':97})
    test3.update({'chris':100})
    test3.update({'charles',94})
    return test1,test2,test3
def main():
    one,two,three = tests()
    one,two,three = actions(one,two,three)
    print (test1,test2,test3)
main()
```

However, when I try to append a new `key:value` to my dicts two errors come up:

First:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\file.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\file.py", line 24, in main
    one,two,three = actions(one,two,three)
  File "C:\file.py", line 14, in actions
    test1.update({'charles',100})
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

Second:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\file.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\file.py", line 24, in main
    one,two,three = actions(one,two,three)
  File "C:\file.py", line 14, in actions
    test1.update({'charles',100})
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 7; 2 is required
```

If I run it over and over again, sometimes the first error comes up, sometimes the other.

I do not want any imports such as `collections`.

Comment: Replace `'charles',94` with `'charles':94`

Comment: Next time you should review your code carefully, because as you can see here, a small error was the fix on your program :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
test1.update({'charles',100})
```

is updating the dict with a set not a dict, which it clearly cannot use to update ... instead of sets pass it dicts

```
test1.update({'charles':100})
```

just to demonstrate

```
{1,2,3,4,4,5,6}   # a set that will contain 1,2,3,4,5,6
{1:2,3:4,4:5}   # a dict with 3 elements dict(1=2,3=4,4=5)
```

Comment: ofc ... you didnt really expect python to actually require imports just for something simple like updating a dictionary did you

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your need you need add new values not update and for that operation you need change update for setdefault method. I have tested on Aptana Studio that code:

```
def tests():
    test1 = {'craig':88, 'jeanie':100}
    test2 = {'craig':85, 'jeanie':95}
    test3 = {'craig':80, 'jeanie':98}
    return test1,test2,test3
def actions(test1,test2,test3):
    test1.setdefault('john',95)
    test1.setdefault('chris',92)
    test1.setdefault('charles',100)
    test2.setdefault('john',100)
    test2.setdefault('chris',96)
    test2.setdefault('charles',98)
    test3.setdefault('john',97)
    test3.setdefault('chris',100)
    test3.setdefault('charles',94)
    return test1,test2,test3
def main():
    one,two,three = tests()
    one,two,three = actions(one,two,three)
    print(one,two,three)
main()
```

and get response:

```
one - {'john': 95, 'charles': 100, 'jeanie': 100, 'chris': 92, 'craig': 88} 
two - {'john': 100, 'charles': 98, 'jeanie': 95, 'chris': 96, 'craig': 85} 
three - {'john': 97, 'charles': 94, 'jeanie': 98, 'chris': 100, 'craig': 80}
```

Your problem is that update search one dictionary with key for update your value and not insert but setdefault insert new pair key:value with that syntax case not exists and return the value for one key case her exists.

Good work for you,

Answer (score 0):

See answer here:

[Add new keys to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/add-to-a-dictionary-in-python)

To update:

```
#### Inserting/Updating value ####
data['a']=1  # updates if 'a' exists, else adds 'a'
# OR #
data.update({'a':1})
# OR #
data.update(dict(a=1))
# OR #
data.update(a=1)
# OR #
data.update([(a,1)])
```

Instead of this:

```
test3.update({'charles',94})
```

Comment: line 4 of your's is where I screwed up. line 8 i didn't know you could do it that way!