# How to turn a list into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary, while-loop

i have this code so far

```
teamNames = []
teams = {}
while True:
    print("Enter team name " + str(len(teamNames) + 1) + (" or press enter to stop."))
    name = input()

    if name == "":
          break

    teamNames = teamNames + [name]

    print("The team names are ")

    for name in teamNames:
          print("    " + name)
```

but now i want to put the teamNames into the blank dictionary created, called teams, with a value of zero, but i dont know how.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/add-key-to-a-dictionary-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand, you want to add all the elements of `teamNames` list as the key of dictionary `teams` and assign the value `0` to each of them.

To do so, use a `for` loop to iterate through the `list` you already have and use the name as the `key` of the dictionary 1 by 1. Like below:

```
for name in teamNames:
    teams[name] =0
```

Answer (score 1):

Outside of and after your existing `for` loop, add this line:

```
teams = {teamName:0 for teamName in teamNames}
```

This structure is called a *dict comprehension*.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
teamNames = []
teams = {}
while True:
    print("Enter team name " + str(len(teamNames) + 1) + (" or press enter to stop."))
    name = input()

    if name == "":
      break

    teamNames = teamNames + [name]
    # add team to dictionary with item value set to 0
    teams[name] = 0
    print("The team names are ")

    for name in teamNames:
       print("    " + name)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could loop over your array like you did

```
for name in teamNames:
      teams[name] = 0
```

that way you should fill the empty dictionary with the values of your array

Answer (score 0):

```
prompt = "Enter the name for team {} or enter to finish: "
teams = {}
name = True #to start the iteration
while name:
    name = input(prompt.format(len(teams)+1))
    if name:
        teams[name] = 0

    print('The teams are:\n    ' + '\n    '.join(teams))
```

Dictionaries already have lists for their keys. If you want the names in a particular order you can swap out the dict for an OrderedDict, but there's no reason to maintain the list of names independently of the teams dict.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting `Python` feature is `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

teams = defaultdict(int)
for name in teamNames:
    teams[name]
```

Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for more info.