# Data type in python like hashes in Perl

Tags: python, perl

I am learning Python now. Before I am working with Perl. In Perl we have multi-level hashes for sorting the data. Are there any types like that available in Python?

For example

```
$hash{$date}{$Origin_Type}++;
```

and

```
$var = {
    '2016-04-08' => {
        GSM  => 32,
        SMPP => 29
    }
}
```

Comment: They are called dictionaries - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/add-key-to-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: **Don't write perl in python. Which is a special case of "Don't line lang-A in lang-B". Because that way you will only get to know stuff from lang-B you already had in lang-A and are starting to miss.** If you are going to write python, write it in python. Read the docs. The data structure is `dict` by the way.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Python dictionaries. They are [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) like Perl hashes.

```
var = {'2016-04-08': {'GSM': 32, 'SMPP': 29}}
>>> var['2016-04-08']
{'SMPP': 29, 'GSM': 32}
>>> var['2016-04-08']['SMPP']
29
```

Note that when iterating over a Python dictionary, just like when iterating over a Perl hash, the order in which you visit the elements is unrelated to the order in which they were inserted.

Comment: *"Note that the order is not preserved in a dictionary"* I am surprised that I read this so often. Order isn't preserved in arrays either. Think about what you mean by *preserving an order*.

Comment: I mean insertion order. e.g. `list.append(value)` will append it to the end. There is no equivalent in `dict`. I don't understand the mistake. Please explain? :)

Comment: userdict = {}
for line in str:
        array = line.split('|', )
        system_id = array[55]
        Origin = array[12]
        if  array[55] != "":
                userdict[Origin][system_id] += 1;


I written my program like this. But Its showing error. I dont know whats the input in the file(To initialize). But I want to calculate How many System_id are present and whats the count per each system_id under that origin