# Converting the comma separated values to Python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I am getting the XML data in below format

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<localPluginManager>
    <plugin>
        <longName>Plugin Usage - Plugin</longName>
        <pinned>false</pinned>
        <shortName>plugin-usage-plugin</shortName>
        <version>0.3</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <longName>Matrix Project Plugin</longName>
        <pinned>false</pinned>
        <shortName>matrix-project</shortName>
        <version>4.5</version>
    </plugin>
</localPluginManager>
```

Used below program to fetch the `"longName"` and `"version"` from the XML

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests
import sys
response = requests.get(<url1>,stream=True)
response.raw.decode_content = True
tree = ET.parse(response.raw)
root = tree.getroot()
for plugin in root.findall('plugin'):
    longName = plugin.find('longName').text
    shortName = plugin.find('shortName').text
    version = plugin.find('version').text
    master01 = longName, version
    print (master01,version)
```

Which gives me below output which I want to convert in dictionary format to process further

```
('Plugin Usage - Plugin', '0.3')
('Matrix Project Plugin', '4.5')
```

Expected Output -

```
dictionary = {"Plugin Usage - Plugin": "0.3", "Matrix Project Plugin": "4.5"}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to get?

Comment: @nick_gabpe - I need to convert my output to Python dictionary

Comment: So your basic question is how to get a dictionary in python and how to add values to it?

Comment: @ jotasi, @ nick_gabpe - Yes exactly, anyhow I need to get the "longName" and respective "version" in a dictionary format so that I can process it further.

Comment: So I guess this is effectively a duplicate that is answered quite well in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8381589/6614295)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add key to a dictionary in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/add-key-to-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import requests
    import sys
    response = requests.get(<url1>,stream=True)
    response.raw.decode_content = True
    tree = ET.parse(response.raw)
    root = tree.getroot()
    mydict = {}
    for plugin in root.findall('plugin'):
        longName = plugin.find('longName').text
        shortName = plugin.find('shortName').text
        version = plugin.find('version').text
        master01 = longName, version
        print (master01,version)
        mydict[longName]=version
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a dictionary at the beginning:

```
my_dict = {}
```

then assign values to this dictionary in the loop:

```
my_dict[longName] = version
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have all your tuples stored in a list, you can iterate over it like this:

```
tuple_list = [('Plugin Usage - Plugin', '0.3'), ('Matrix Project Plugin', '4.5')]
dictionary = {}

for item in tuple_list:
    dictionary[item[0]] = item[1]
```

Or, in Python 3, a dict comprehension instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, actually.  First, you initialize the dictionary before the loop, then you add key-value pairs as you get them:

```
dictionary = {}
for plugin in root.findall('plugin'):
    ...
    dictionary[longName] = version # In place of the print call
```