# update python dictionary when key is an array

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary

I have already seen this post [Add key to a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/add-key-to-a-dictionary-in-python) but i am running now on a typical scenario where key is a array and i want to add new value to that array. Here is my condition now.

I am reading a database column which contains a json string and i have to modify the string(add some additional values to the string and keep in json format) and update the column with updated json string. Json structure is like the following

```
{
"tenantCreationDate": 1476869059806,
"rdVersion": "2016a06.01",
"products": [{
    "productName": "Core",
    "currentVerison": "2016a06.01",
    "versionHistory": [{
        "startDate": 1476869059829,
        "upgradedBy": "squire",
        "version": "2016a06.01",
        "endDate": null
    }]
}, {
    "productName": "Capture",
    "currentVerison": "2016a06.01",
    "versionHistory": [{
        "startDate": 1476869059829,
        "upgradedBy": "squire",
        "version": "2016a06.01",
        "endDate": null
    }]
}, {
    "productName": "Vault",
    "currentVerison": "2016a06.01",
    "versionHistory": [{
        "startDate": 1476869059829,
        "upgradedBy": "squire",
        "version": "2016a06.01",
        "endDate": null
    }]
}, {
    "productName": "LVA",
    "currentVerison": "2016a06.01",
    "versionHistory": [{
        "startDate": 1476869059829,
        "upgradedBy": "squire",
        "version": "2016a06.01",
        "endDate": null
    }]
}, {
    "productName": "Correspondence",
    "currentVerison": "2016a06.01",
    "versionHistory": [{
        "startDate": 1476869059829,
        "upgradedBy": "squire",
        "version": "2016a06.01",
        "endDate": null
    }]
}]

}
```

As you can see ***products*** is an array under which ***versionHistory*** is another array and i want to add another version to this array and post it to database.So what i did first is to read the column from db and converted to json

```
metadata = json.loads(json.dumps(row));
```

Now my question is how i will add another version to the array and submit the updated data to the database column and let say after update version history should look like --

```
"versionHistory": [{
        "startDate": 1476869059829,
        "upgradedBy": "squire",
        "version": "2016a06.01",
        "endDate": null
    },
    {
        "startDate": 12345678,
        "upgradedBy": "admin",
        "version": "2016.07.02",
        "endDate": 123456
    }
    ]
```

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You want to apply update on version history to any specific product or all the products?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please show us what you've tried by posting your code and and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ??? (hint: it's so trivial that you would probably have spend less time solving it by yourself than posting this).

Comment: Also, your dictionary keys are not an arrays... your array members are dictionaries though... so just append another one... should be easy.

Comment: @Moinuddin Quadri, it can be either specific product or all products depending upon use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
for obj in metadata["products"]:
    if obj["productName"]==nameToLookFor:
        obj["versionHistory"].append(newObject)
```

this will add the version to the product with the name you specify in nameToLookFor