# In python, why only the last element of a list is returned when use for loop?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, return

The script is shown as follows:

```
#add powerfactory.pyd path to python path
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\Program Files\\DIgSILENT\\PowerFactory 2017 
SP2\\Python\\3.6")

if __name__ == "__main__":
#import powerfactory module

    import powerfactory

#start powerfactory module in unattended mode (engine mode)
app=powerfactory.GetApplication()



#active project
project=app.ActivateProject('Python Test') #active project "Python Test"
# prj=app.GetActiveProject   #returns the actived project

#run python code below
ldf=app.GetFromStudyCase('ComLdf') #calling loadflow command 
ldf.Execute() #executing the load flow command

#get the list of lines contained in the project
lines=app.GetCalcRelevantObjects('*.ElmLne') #returns all relevant objects

for line in lines: #get each element out of list
    name=line.loc_name #get name of the line
    value=line.GetAttribute('c:loading') 
    print('Loading of the line: %s = %.2f%%'%(name,value))
```

By simply input:

```
>>>name
```

The returned result is the last element:

```
>>>'Line3'
```

I have also tried using dict(), but it still not working. Therefore, it would be so much appreciated that if someone could offer me some advice.

Comment: your print statement is outside of the for loop

Comment: Ha. I got it, such a embarrassed. Thank you so much.

Comment: But again, when I simply type name, the returned result is still last element.

Comment: how many elements does the `lines` list have?

Comment: `name` is reassigned for each line, so it is left with the value of the last line.

Comment: since you have not assigned variable `name` outside the loop, so it will stay still. Which means you'll get the exact value you had in the last loop. If you want access to another name - line couple, you'll have to reassign them.

Comment: The list has 3 elements. I have tried define it outside the loop using dictionary, but still not working. I do believe there is a way which can be able to write the name and value into a matrix like the ''for'' loop using in MATLAB.

Comment: A dictionary will also work here. Though if you don't need to have a special name for the keys of each element, I'd stick with a list. See here for a simple example on using a dictionary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want that last for loop to look something like this:

```
name = []
for line in lines: #get each element out of list
    name.append(line.loc_name) #get name of the line
    value=line.GetAttribute('c:loading') 
    print('Loading of the line: %s = %.2f%%'%(name,value))
```

This won't overwrite the value of name for each loop iteration.