# Use a dictionary to calculate most common letter

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that will take in a string and use a dictionary to calculate and return the most common letter in that string. I believe that my code is close to working; however, I get a "cant assign to function call" error on line 5.

Here is my code so far:

```
def mostCommon(myString):
    charCount = []
    for c in myString.lower():
        if c in charCount:
            charCount(c) += 1
        else:
            charCount(c) = 1
    myVal = 0
    myKey = 0
    for key, value in charCount.lower():
        if value > myVal:
           myVal = value
           myKey = key
        return charCount
```

Comment: Quite a number of problems, the present being the use of `()` instead of `[]`. If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, you can use `collection.Counter`'s `most_common` method to achieve the same thing.

Comment: you've assigned a *list* to `charCount`. Anyway, you index into a list or dict with `[c]` not with `(c)`, which would *call* the object (hence, the interpreter complaining about you trying to assign to a function call). Also, you then do `charCount.lower()`, neither dict objects nor list objects have a `lower` method. Also, ignoring that, even if you *did* have a `dict` as `charCount`, iterating over it like `for k, v in my_dict:` will give you a `ValueError,` since iterating over a `dict` iterates over the *keys*, and you try to unpack a single value into `k, v`....

Comment: My advice: while you are still getting a hang of a language, you should do your best to tackle one bit of your program at a time. Your current solution is replete with errors, but you should be testing your code as you write it, so you aren't stacking mistakes on top of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your function with the errors corrected.

```
def mostCommon(myString):
    charCount = {}
    for c in myString.lower():
        if c in charCount:
            charCount[c] += 1
        else:
            charCount[c] = 1
    myVal = 0
    myKey = 0
    for key, value in charCount.items():
        if value > myVal:
           myVal = value
           myKey = key
    return myKey
```

Here's a much simpler way of doing it

```
from collections import Counter

def mostCommon(myString):
    return Counter(myString).most_common(1)[0][0]
```

Comment: I'm a fan of `dict.setdefault` here. `for c in myString.lower(): charCount.setdefault(c, 0) += 1`

Comment: @AdamSmith I'd probably go `defaultdict` myself, but I wanted to preserve as much of their code as possible to make it easier to compare the two and pick out changes

Comment: This code does work now however the output is not whats expected. I should see >>>text = "Beware the mighty mummy" >>>answer =mostCommon(text) >>>print(answer). The answer would be m

Answer (score 0):

Well you defined charCount as a list, and then tried to call it like a function. If you want charCount to just be a number, just set it to 0 before your for loop.

Or to use a dict

```
charCount = {}
for c in myString.lower():
    if c in charCount:
        charCount[c] += 1
```

Comment: I think `charCount` is supposed to be a `dict`

Answer (score 0):

I think you intended `charCount` to be a `dict` not a `list`. Here is a simple solution using the `max` function:

```
def mostCommon2(myString):
    charCount = {}
    for c in myString.lower():
        if c in charCount:
            charCount[c] += 1
        else:
            charCount[c] = 1
    return max(charCount, key=charCount.get)
```

Answer (score 0):

here after a few things that can help.

1. The correct syntax to declare a dictionary is `charCount = {}`
2. you cannot create an item with `charCount(c)`, you better do `charcount[c] = 'c'`

To add element to a dictionnary: [Add new keys to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary)