# How to add an extra element to a multi dimensional array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a multidimensional dictionary to which I am unable to add a new element. Can you please help with this query :

```
items = {'Warner': {'balls': 4, 'runs': 6},
         'Dhawan': {'balls': 2, 'runs': 0},
         'yuvaraj': {'balls': 1.5, 'runs': 32},
         'scouts': {'balls': 3, 'runs': 15}
        }
```

to this, I want to add a new element

```
items['varun'] = [{'balls': 2}, {'runs': 2}]
```

However, the above line throws an error saying key error Varun.

Comment: Are you sure you are not missing something? I don't see anything would throw that error and it does work in my python, both 2 and 3.

Comment: Please include all of the relevant code and the complete traceback in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new keys to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

In your first piece

```
 `items = {'Warner': {'balls': 4,   'runs': 6 },
         'Dhawan':  {'balls': 2,   'runs': 0 },
          'yuvaraj': {'balls': 1.5, 'runs': 32},
          'scouts':   {'balls': 3,   'runs': 15},
        }`
```

you've got a `dict` matched to a `key`, but then you are trying to match a `list` of `dict`, instead of just `dict`.
Try this:

```
items['varun']  = {'balls':2 , 'runs' : 2}
```

Output:

```
{'Warner': {'balls': 4, 'runs': 6},
 'Dhawan': {'balls': 2, 'runs': 0},
 'yuvaraj': {'balls': 1.5, 'runs': 32},
 'scouts': {'balls': 3, 'runs': 15}, 
 'varun': {'balls': 2, 'runs': 2}}
```