# list element removing and adding,

Tags: python, python-2.7

Please don't mark this as an answered question because I think it is not about the general program but here is a specific thing that I don't realize.
So the problem is when I run the program it should first remove the "araba" string and then insert "car" string in its existing place. So I uptaded the dict everytime and print it but nothing happens? Thx

```
tr_mean=["araba","otobus","kus"]
en_mean=["car","bus","dog"]
dictionary={}
for x in tr_mean:
  index=tr_mean.index(x)
  dictionary[x]=en_mean[index]



print tr_mean.index("araba")
for x in tr_mean:
  index=tr_mean.index(x)
  dictionary[x]=en_mean[index]
print words
del tr_mean[tr_mean.index("araba")]
for x in tr_mean:
  index=tr_mean.index(x)
  dictionary[x]=en_mean[index]
print words
tr_mean.insert(0,"car")
for x in tr_mean:
  index=tr_mean.index(x)
  dictionary[x]=en_mean[index]

print words
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit about the problem you're trying to solve, because I have to imagine there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Plz edit the question to show to input and expected output.You can take help [ask]

Comment: what is `words`?

Comment: I should have written dictionary instead of words

Comment: @AniketBote I think I clearly show that I expect that "araba" to be removed and then add "car" to it's existing place but It just doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tr_mean = ["araba", "otobus", "kus"]
en_mean = ["car", "bus", "dog"]
dictionary = {}
for x in tr_mean:
    index = tr_mean.index(x)
    dictionary[x] = en_mean[index]

print tr_mean.index("araba")
```

Here you are just doing the same thing again, not needed.

```
# for x in tr_mean:
#     index = tr_mean.index(x)
#     dictionary[x] = en_mean[index]
```

You did not define `words`, I guess you meant to use `dictionnary`?

```
print dictionary
```

Here you remove `"araba"` from `tr_mean`, so `tr_mean` is now `["otobus", "kus"]`

```
del tr_mean[tr_mean.index("araba")]
```

After that, I'm guessing you try to "reset" the dictionnary

```
for x in tr_mean:
        index = tr_mean.index(x)
        dictionary[x] = en_mean[index]
    print dictionary
```

but all you are doing is:

```
dictionary["otobus"] = "bus"
dictionary["kus"] = "dog",
```

araba still exists in `dictionnary`!!!

Before you assign the new values, clear the dictionary with `dictionary.clear()`

```
dictionary.clear()
for x in tr_mean:
    index = tr_mean.index(x)
    dictionary[x] = en_mean[index]
print dictionary
```

Or better yet, remove that last block of code and simply delete `"araba"` from `dictionary`

```
del dictionary["araba"]
```

Every thing else is left unchanged.

```
tr_mean.insert(0, "car")
for x in tr_mean:
    index = tr_mean.index(x)
    dictionary[x] = en_mean[index]

print dictionary
```

EDIT:
If you want to add "car" as a new key to your dictionary using the value of "araba", you can do something like this:

```
dictionary["car"] = dictionary.pop("araba")
```

`.pop()` will delete the "araba" key and give the value associated with "araba" to the new key `dictionary["car"]`

Comment: Yeah thanks that seems to be the problem. I'm new to dictionaries and as I understood the problem is I deleted "araba" from tr_mean but the meaning "car" is not deleted from en_mean and I didn't delete the "araba" key from dictionary. So it didn't do anything to "araba" key. I think yes :D

Comment: Found this post on dictionaries: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8381589/7612911.