# python append dictionary in nested dictionary

Tags: python

i've this dictionary:

```
appointment = { soccer = {
                           day : 20,
                           month : april
                          }
               }
```

how can i insert this dictio in the same structure?

```
appointment = { gym = {
                           day : 5,
                           month : may
                          }
               }
```

expected output:

```
appointment = { soccer = {
                           day : 20,
                           month : april
                          },
                 gym = {
                           day : 5,
                           month : may
                          }
               }
```

how can i connect this dictio by code?

Comment: This is not valid Python code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using python 3.5 or greater you can merge your dictionaries using the following syntax:

```
appointment1 = { 'soccer' : {
                        'day' : 20,
                       'month' : 'april'
                       }

            }
appointment2 = { 'soccer' : {
                        'day' : 20,
                        'month' : 'april'
                       },
              'gym' : {
                        'day' : 5,
                        'month' : 'may'
                       }
            }
appointment = {**appointment1,**appointment2}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the dicts already exist you might look at `dict.update()`.

Short answer is do this:

```
>>> appointment = { 'soccer' : { 'day': 20, 'month': 'april' } }
>>> appointment2 = { 'gym' : { 'day': 5, 'month': 'may' } }
>>> appointment.update(appointment2)
>>> appointment
{'gym': {'day': 5, 'month': 'may'}, 'soccer': {'day': 20, 'month': 'april'}}
```

But if you're making these dicts it makes more sense to just add new entries in the usual way (See: [Add new keys to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary)):

```
>>> appointment = { 'soccer' : { 'day': 20, 'month': 'april' } }
>>> appointment['gym'] = {'day': 5, 'month': 'may'}
>>> appointment
{'gym': {'day': 5, 'month': 'may'}, 'soccer': {'day': 20, 'month': 'april'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `dict.update()` method

> D.update([E, ]**F) -> None.
>
> Update D from dict/iterable E and F.
>
> If E is present and has a .keys() method, then does:  for k in E: D[k] = E[k]
>
> If E is present and lacks a .keys() method, then does:  for k, v in E: D[k] = v
>
> In either case, this is followed by: for k in F:  D[k] = F[k]

Your case,

```
appointment = { 'soccer' : { 'day' : 20, 'month' :'april' }}
appointment2 = {'gym': {'day': 20, 'month': 'april'}}

# update appointment with appointment2 values
appointment.update(appointment2)
{'soccer': {'day': 20, 'month': 'april'}, 'gym': {'day': 20, 'month': 'april'}}
```

And `appointment2` variable remains unchanged, when `appointment` variable is updated in place.