# Insert a new calculated value into a Json

Tags: python, json

I have a `JSON` that look like:

```
[{
    "lat": 43.96063343238712,
    "panoid": "sffcNG69c2kdZwEuYp1htw",
    "lon": 3.098330084924494
}, {
    "lat": 43.96052745649745,
    "panoid": "2rJPv_r0gC5FBPLZK5vHDA",
    "lon": 3.098487422195691
} and so on... ]
```

I want for each element (means pair of brackets), to add a key `calc` that is equal to

```
(value of "lat") - 50
```

How could I do to update my `JSON` like that? I guess I should convert the `JSON` into a `dictionary`. But how to proceed after?

Comment: You'll need to parse the JSON into a list of dictionary at some point, so where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I don't really see how to add the new row and then populate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new keys to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: JSON doesn't have "rows", it has keys and values. You add a pairing in python just as you would a regular dictionary. JSON is parsed into a dictionary, and dictionaries can be written out as JSON files, but that's an implementation detail.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answers

Comment: @cricket_007 JSON isn't just dictionaries, it can have arrays too.

Comment: @Term True, lists and primitives are there. For the purpose of the problem, though, a dictionary would be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to load the string into a list. Iterate over the dictionaries in the list and set an attribute - `calc` - to be the `lat` value minus `50`.

Finally, if required, dump the list back to a string with an optional `indent` arg for pretty-printing.

```
import json
s = '''[{
    "lat": 43.96063343238712,
    "panoid": "sffcNG69c2kdZwEuYp1htw",
    "lon": 3.098330084924494
}, {
    "lat": 43.96052745649745,
    "panoid": "2rJPv_r0gC5FBPLZK5vHDA",
    "lon": 3.098487422195691
}]'''
l = json.loads(s)
for d in l:
    d['calc'] = d['lat'] - 50
print(json.dumps(l, indent=4))
```

giving:

```
[
    {
        "lat": 43.96063343238712,
        "panoid": "sffcNG69c2kdZwEuYp1htw",
        "lon": 3.098330084924494,
        "calc": -6.0393665676128805
    },
    {
        "lat": 43.96052745649745,
        "panoid": "2rJPv_r0gC5FBPLZK5vHDA",
        "lon": 3.098487422195691,
        "calc": -6.039472543502548
    }
]
```