# Python: Add to existing dictionary value if key exists in while loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop, append

I have this code right now.

```
current_assets = {}
yes_list=["yes", "Yes", "y", "Y"]

while create_bs in (yes_list):

    key=str(input("Enter a specific account.\nExamples: Checking Account 
    Balance, Investment in XYZ Corp., Parking Fine Payable, Note Payable, 
    Receviable From John Smith\n"))

    value=float(input("Enter the value/historical cost of the asset or 
    liability.\n"))

    account_type=str(input("What type of account is this?\nOptions: 1) 
    Current Assets 2) Noncurrent Assets 3) Current Liabilities 4) Noncurrent 
    Liabilities\n"))

    if account_type in ("1", "Current Assets", "current assets", "CA"):
        current_assets.update({key:value})
    if key in current_assets:
        current_assets[key].append({key:value})
```

There are two problems occurring when trying to run this:

1. I receive an

   ```
   AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'append'
   ```
2. The value seems to add to itself twice. So for example instead of

   ```
   {Cash: 100} and {Cash: 200} becoming {Cash: (100, 200)}, it becomes {Cash: 400}
   ```

Comment: What data structure is   'current_assets`?

Comment: If `current_assets[key]` is a float value, you can't `append` another float onto it.  Instead the value should be a list which _contains_ one or more floats.

Comment: @Nick dictionary

Comment: @JohnGordon I fixed that part, it still shows a list of [200, 200] instead of [100, 200]

Answer (score 0):

Please lets use defaultdict from the collections package, and then convert it to dict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)
print(data)
#defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {})
data[1].append(10.5)
print(data)
#defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [10.5]})
data[1].append(10.5)
print(data)
print(dict(data))
#defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [10.5, 10.5]})
#{1: [10.5, 10.5]}
```

Comment: @metincs You can add new value to your existing key, is it what you wanted?

Comment: @metincs Try to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary for having best practices

Comment: @metincs please check my answer again