# MySQL row-column-value format to python dictionary

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am relatively new to Python (and Django) and have some data in a MySQL database in a row-column-value format

Django Model "UserParameters":

```
user_id | param     | value
-----------------------------------
123     | param_1   | xxx
123     | param_2   | yyy
123     | param_3   | zzz
123     | param_4   | aaa
123     | param_5   | bbb
123     | param_6   | xxx
...
...
456     | param_1   | sse
456     | param_2   | aca
456     | param_3   | cce
456     | param_4   | dwe
456     | param_5   | cck
456     | param_6   | aq1
...
...
789     | param_1   | zzz
...
```

I'm trying to get this data in MySQL into a dictionary in the following format:

```
users = {
    123: {'param_1': 'xxx', 'param_2': 'yyy', 'param_3': 'zzz', 'param_4': 'aaa', 'param_5': 'bbb', 'param_6': 'xxx'}, 
    456: {'param_1': 'sse', 'param_2': 'aca', 'param_3': 'cce', 'param_4': 'dwe', 'param_5': 'cck', 'param_6': 'aq1'}, 
    789: {'param_1': 'zzz', .....
}
```

So far, I've tried

```
users = {}
users_params = UserParameters.objects.all().values()
for u in users_params:
    users[u['user_id']].add(u['param'], u['value'])
```

This gives me a key error. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Thank you!

Example content from user_params

```
{'id': 695, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk1_d2_survey_1', 'value': 768}
{'id': 708, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk3_d1_survey_2', 'value': 781}
{'id': 703, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk2_d2_survey_1', 'value': 776}
{'id': 720, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk14_d3_survey', 'value': 793}
{'id': 714, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk3_d2_survey_4', 'value': 787}
{'id': 696, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk1_d2_survey_2', 'value': 769}
{'id': 709, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk3_d1_survey_3', 'value': 782}
{'id': 691, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk1_d1_survey_1', 'value': 764}
{'id': 704, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk2_d2_survey_2', 'value': 777}
{'id': 699, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk2_d1_survey_1', 'value': 772}
{'id': 715, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk4_d1_survey', 'value': 788}
{'id': 697, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk1_d2_survey_3', 'value': 770}
{'id': 710, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk3_d1_survey_4', 'value': 783}
{'id': 692, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk1_d1_survey_2', 'value': 765}
{'id': 705, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk2_d2_survey_3', 'value': 778}
{'id': 700, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk2_d1_survey_2', 'value': 773}
{'id': 716, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk4_d2_survey', 'value': 789}
{'id': 698, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk1_d2_survey_4', 'value': 771}
{'id': 711, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk3_d2_survey_1', 'value': 784}
{'id': 693, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk1_d1_survey_3', 'value': 766}
{'id': 706, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk2_d2_survey_4', 'value': 779}
{'id': 701, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk2_d1_survey_3', 'value': 774}
{'id': 717, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk4_d3_survey', 'value': 790}
{'id': 718, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk14_d1_survey', 'value': 791}
{'id': 712, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk3_d2_survey_2', 'value': 785}
{'id': 694, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk1_d1_survey_4', 'value': 767}
{'id': 707, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk3_d1_survey_1', 'value': 780}
{'id': 702, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk2_d1_survey_4', 'value': 775}
{'id': 719, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk14_d2_survey', 'value': 792}
{'id': 713, 'user_id': 5063, 'param': 'wk3_d2_survey_3', 'value': 786}
{'id': 676, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk2_d2_survey_4', 'value': 749}
{'id': 663, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk1_d1_survey_3', 'value': 736}
{'id': 671, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk2_d1_survey_3', 'value': 744}
{'id': 687, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk4_d3_survey', 'value': 760}
{'id': 682, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk3_d2_survey_2', 'value': 755}
{'id': 688, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk14_d1_survey', 'value': 761}
{'id': 677, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk3_d1_survey_1', 'value': 750}
{'id': 664, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk1_d1_survey_4', 'value': 737}
{'id': 672, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk2_d1_survey_4', 'value': 745}
{'id': 683, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk3_d2_survey_3', 'value': 756}
{'id': 689, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk14_d2_survey', 'value': 762}
{'id': 678, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk3_d1_survey_2', 'value': 751}
{'id': 665, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk1_d2_survey_1', 'value': 738}
{'id': 673, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk2_d2_survey_1', 'value': 746}
{'id': 684, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk3_d2_survey_4', 'value': 757}
{'id': 690, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk14_d3_survey', 'value': 763}
{'id': 679, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk3_d1_survey_3', 'value': 752}
{'id': 666, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk1_d2_survey_2', 'value': 739}
{'id': 674, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk2_d2_survey_2', 'value': 747}
{'id': 661, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk1_d1_survey_1', 'value': 734}
{'id': 685, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk4_d1_survey', 'value': 758}
{'id': 669, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk2_d1_survey_1', 'value': 742}
{'id': 680, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk3_d1_survey_4', 'value': 753}
{'id': 667, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk1_d2_survey_3', 'value': 740}
{'id': 675, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk2_d2_survey_3', 'value': 748}
{'id': 662, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk1_d1_survey_2', 'value': 735}
{'id': 670, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk2_d1_survey_2', 'value': 743}
{'id': 686, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk4_d2_survey', 'value': 759}
{'id': 681, 'user_id': 5062, 'param': 'wk3_d2_survey_1', 'value': 754}
```

Adding traceback error

```
(venv_demo) $ python3 manage.py shell < test.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/mklimeck/venv_demo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/mklimeck/venv_demo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/mklimeck/venv_demo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/mklimeck/venv_demo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/mklimeck/venv_demo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 92, in handle
    exec(sys.stdin.read())
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

KeyError: 5063
```

Models.py

```
class UserParameters(models.Model):

    user_id = models.ForeignKey(Users, to_field='user_id', db_column='user_id', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    param = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "user_parameters"
        unique_together = ("user_id", "param")
```

Comment: Could you share some example contents from users_params?

Comment: Added example content. Thank you!

Comment: So it seems you want to drop the `id` and add `param_1` to `param_n` to each user_id record ... kind of like a custom groupby... is that correct? Is order of the param numbering important?

Comment: Also share the traceback error you are getting and models.py file.

Comment: @brennan That's correct. The order of the param numbering is not important.

Comment: @shubhitgarg added traceback and Models.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary) exploring different ways to add keys to a dictionary.

For what I think you are trying to accomplish (it sounds like a nested dictionary or a dictionary of dictionaries) you might try something like:

```
for u in users_params:
    user_id = u['user_id']
    if user_id not in users:
        users[user_id] = {}
    users[user_id][u['param']] = u['value']

# For users with key pairs like
# {5063: {'wk1_d2_survey_1': 768, 'wk3_d1_survey_2': 781 ...}}
```

Edit: Removed alternative

Comment: Thank you, @brennan. Your 2nd alternative is exactly what I was looking for. And thank you for pointing me to that discussion on adding keys to a dictionary. The step I was missing was "if user_id not in users:"

Comment: Great to hear, I'll nuke the first one. Be careful not to overwrite key/values if that's an issue. Good luck!