# List in dict is being overriden when I add a sec. list to dict

Tags: python-3.x

I want to add `username` and `dateTimeHold` to bigData, if it already exists, then I only want to add `dateTimeHold`, else add `username` and `dateTimeHold`.

When I'm trying with this code, it's just overwriting:

```
dateTimeHold = ('09-07-2019', '09.00 - 16.00', 'Red')
username = 'James'
bigData = {
        'Peter': [('08-07-2019', '06.00 - 07.00', 'Blue')], 
        'James': [('08-07-2019', '06.00 - 07.00', 'Blue')]
        }

if username != bigData.keys():
    listTime = []
    listTime.append(dateTimeHold)
    bigData[username] = listTime
else:
    bigData[username][listTime].append(dateTimeHold)
```

Output:

```
{
    'Peter': [('08-07-2019', '06.00 - 07.00', 'Blue')], 
    'James': [('09-07-2019', '09.00 - 16.00', 'Red')]
}
```

What I want it to do:

```
{
    'Peter': [('08-07-2019', '06.00 - 07.00', 'Blue')], 
    'James': [('08-07-2019', '06.00 - 07.00', 'Blue'), ('09-07-2019', '09.00 - 16.00', 'Red')]
}
```

Comment: What is `listTime` in your `else`? (may want to start looking there).  I.e. `bigData[username][listTime].append(dateTimeHold)` should be `bigData[username].append(dateTimeHold)`

Comment: Your if condition will never be true, by the way

Comment: it refers to the list there allready have been created up in the if. I dont know if its correct im new to python

Comment: You should look into scopes... as it sits you code is bug prone.

Comment: As juanpa pointed out your `if` is never entered.

Comment: if i change != to == the the else statment works but i get an keyError at the first if statment

Comment: @ChristianGræsborg Exactly, read my first comment. You are trying to use a key on a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proper sintax**

```
if username not in bigData.keys():
    bigData[username] = [dateTimeHold]
else:
    bigData[username].append(dateTimeHold)
```

---

**About your if condition**

Using `if username != bigData.keys():` will always be true because **anything your variable username is** will be different of `dict_keys(['Peter', 'James'])`.

If you want to see if a value is inside a list you should use `in` or `not in` instead

- `'Peter' != bigData.keys()` is **True**
- `'Peter' not in bigData.keys()` is **False**

**About your else**

The sintax is not right, listTime doesn't exists in your else scope.

Besides that check out this content of [adding new keys in dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary) to understand why `bigData[username][listTime].append(dateTimeHold)` generates an error and why`bigData[username].append(dateTimeHold)` works.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code and see the comments in line for the corrections

```
dateTimeHold = ('09-07-2019', '09.00 - 16.00', 'Red')
username = 'James'
bigData = {'Peter': [('08-07-2019', '06.00 - 07.00', 'Blue')], 
           'James': [('08-07-2019', '06.00 - 07.00', 'Blue')}
if username not in bigData.keys(): #1. Check for the username in the keys
    listTime = []
    listTime.append(dateTimeHold)
    bigData[username] = listTime
else:
    bigData[username].append(dateTimeHold) #2.right way to append
```