# Can anyone explain the eval() and dict() functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

Code:

```
price_dict["Price"] = price_dict["Price"].apply(lambda x : dict(eval(x)) )
df = price_dict['Price'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Can anyone explain to me the above equations?

Comment: Show some examples of what `price_dict` contains, then it will become clearer what `eval` does.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please provide us with enough of your code to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.? I would highly suggest that you edit your question following the guidelines of [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You may also want to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get more familiar with SO and what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

`eval` basically runs python code from a written (string) expression, and `dict` turns that result (whatever it is) into a python dictionary object, assuming that's possible.

You should read up more on both: [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval), [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict)

Answer (score 0):

You simple google and will find nicely explained Answers:

For [eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do) read this linke

For [dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary) read this link

**dict()** - The Python dict() is a built-in function that returns a dictionary object or simply creates a dictionary in Python.

**eval()**  - eval() evaluates the passed string as a Python expression and returns the result. For example, eval("1 + 1") interprets and executes the expression "1 + 1" and returns the result (2)