# In Python, I have a Dictionary, how do I add a new key on the first Index?

Tags: python, dictionary

For example:

```
MyDict = {"dog" : 3, "cat" : 5}
```

How do I make it like this:

```
MyDict = {"cow" : 7, "dog" : 3, "cat" : 5}
```

With minimal code?

Comment: `MyDict["cow"] = 7`? BTW for a plain dict the order of items in not guaranteed...

Comment: @SergeBallesta It is in CPython 3.7 and above, but the premise of the question (ie why it even matters to OP) is not clear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add new keys to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/how-can-i-add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: Even though order is technically maintained in dictionaries now, you might be better off using a different data structure that's meant to preserve order. For example, you could have a list of tuples, where each tuple represents a key-value pair: [ ( "cow", 7 ),  ( "dog", 3 ),  ( "cat", 5 ) ]

Comment: @Matvei That kills O(1) lookup for O(n) iteration

Comment: @DeepSpace That's true. You could improve lookup speed by maintaining a separate dictionary to track the indices of the list elements. Ultimately, it depends on how much data will be stored and how often it needs to be accessed or moved.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming we're talking Python 3.7+ (so that dictionaries have fixed order), this should do:

```
MyDict = {"dog" : 3, "cat" : 5}
MyDict = {"cow": 7, **MyDict}
```