# Python TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' in dictionary

Tags: python

## I am getting this TypeError in this simple code, appending a value to a dictionary.

```
dict = {}
dict['key' : 'value']
print(dict)
```

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/23232/python-add-to-dictionary

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add new keys to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/how-can-i-add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

```
dict = {}
dict['key'] = 'value'
print(dict)
```

`[index1 :index2 ]` is list slice operation, which will not work on dict

Answer (score 0):

well you can do much more 
d={}
for appending to it you can do

`d={'key1':'value1','key2':'value'}`

also

```
d.update(key3:'val3')
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can't add like this, it's a dictionary that takes key and value as a separate entity like

```
dict['key'] = 'value'
```

After doing this, the dictionary will automatically convert itself like-

```
dict['key' : 'value']
```