# Python - Append dictionary in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python and have a perhaps basic question.. I have a dictionary, and want to add another dictionary to a key in the first dictionary :)

So currently the dictionary look like this:

```
{
    "name": "custname",
    "slug": "custslug",
    "group": "1"
}
```

And I need it to "append" another dictionary to an existing.. I guess It is a nested dictionary I need.

```
{
    "name": "custname",
    "slug": "custslug",
    "custom_fields": {
        "NavID": "10023"
    },
    "group": "1",
 }
```

Comment: `dict[key] = other_dict`

Comment: Do you mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/how-can-i-add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python?

Answer (score 3):

In case you want a nested dictionary use the below method -

```
d1 = {"name": "custname","slug": "custslug","group": "1"}
d1["custom_fields"] = {"NavID": "10023"}
print(d1)
```

This will give the output you wanted.

Or if you want to merge two dictionaries and update the values, you may use the update method.

```
d1 = {"name": "custname","slug": "custslug","group": "1"}
d2 = {"NavID": "10023"}
d1.update(d2)
```

The output here will be

```
{"name": "custname","slug": "custslug","group": "1","NavID": "10023"}
```

Comment: Second dictionary is not a nested dictionary. This is not what OP meant.

Comment: But when I convert my data frame to a dict with this line
new_tenants = nav_kunder.to_dict(orient='records')

I then get a TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str when I use your first suggestion

Comment: I was also confused with what the question asked.. So I came up with both update method and assigning the second dictionary to a key of the first dictionary and thus making  it a nested dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

```
dict = {
    "name": "custname",
    "slug": "custslug",
    "group": "1"
}

another_dict = {
        "NavID": "10023"
    }

dict['Custom_fields'] = another_dict
```

Comment: Second dictionary is not a nested dictionary.

Comment: i have added another dictionary to a key in the first dictionary in order to get a nested dictionary as asked in question

Answer (score 0):

Great question! This will work.

```
d1 = {
    "name": "custname",
    "slug": "custslug",
    "group": "1"
}
d2 = {"NavID": "10023"}
d1["custom_fields"] = d2
```

Comment: This is not what OP meant in his question I think.  He says the second dictionary is a nested dictionary. You are adding a dictionary explicitly to a key. I think you should clarify once.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append or merge 2 dictionaries, you can use `update` method.

Below is how you can do it :

```
d1 = {
    "name": "custname",
    "slug": "custslug",
    "group": "1"
}
d2 = {"custom_fields": {"NavID": "10023"}}


d1.update(d2)

print(d1)
```

OUTPUT :

```
>>> {'group': '1', 'name': 'custname', 'custom_fields': {'NavID': '10023'}, 'slug': 'custslug'}
```