# Adding a new dictionary element?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a simple code of having a dictionary inside a list, how do you add an another element to them? The code is as follow:

```
Cars = []
Cars.append({"make": "Tesla", "colour": "red"})
print(Cars)
Cars.append({"make": "Toyota", "colour": "green"})
Cars.append({"make": "Ford", "colour": "white"})
print(Cars)
```

I want it to add a new dictionary element to the list showing year of manufacture so that when I print it shows this

```
[{'make': Tesla, 'colour': 'red',’year’:2020}
,{"make": "Toyota", "colour": "green",’year’:2020}
,{"make": "Ford", "colour": "white",’year’:2020}
]
```

Comment: You have to do this using the list index, like: `Cars[0]['year'] = 2020`

Comment: @GAEfan And how do you know which index?

Comment: You don't.  You'd have to write a script to test and find the car you want.  unless you want to add the same value to all, then just use a loop.

Comment: @GAEfan Why would you do either of those with an index?

Comment: @GAEfan thx very much, but do you know why I got marked down, Im kind new to Stackoverflow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add new keys to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/how-can-i-add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: Your question is getting voted down because this is a basic question, and you need to do some research first before asking a question on stackoverflow. This is a duplicate question.

Comment: I guess they figure this is a basic python question, and you could have easily Googled it or found similar questions here.  This is rather basic list & dictionary ops.

Comment: Thx this really helped. But what will happen if my reputation falls below 0?

Comment: @VibertexKhan If your reputation falls below 0, you'll have to pay a fine. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48037/824076).

Answer (score 2):

```py
for car in Cars:
    car["year"] = 2020
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the list `Cars`, and for every element add a new key-value in the dictionary

```
for car in Cars:
    car['year'] = 2020
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a for loop to add to each dict in the list like so.

```
for itm in Cars:
    itm["year"] = 2020
```

Comment: It's the same as the answer posted before yours, except with a less meaningful variable name.

Comment: But it's not, not helpful. Just don't respond to it next time maybe...

Answer (score -1):

```
#step 1- loop through the list

for car in Cars:
    #Step 2 - append the dictionary with key as year and value as 2020
    car["year"] = 2020
```

Hope this help Happy coding

Answer (score -2):

You can simply loop through all element of the list and add, below code will update the Cars list elements

```
[car.update({'year':2020}) for car in Cars]
```