# Why am I gettng a KeyError when adding a key to a dictonary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key

I am still trying to learn the ins and outs of Python dictionaries.  When I run this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
d = {}
d['foo']['bar'] = 1
```

I get `KeyError: 'foo'`. But in [How can I add new keys to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/how-can-i-add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary)  it says that "you create a new key\value pair on a dictionary by assigning a value to that key. If the key doesn't exist, it's added and points to that value. If it exists, the current value it points to is overwritten." So why am I getting the key error?

Comment: you need to do `d['foo']={} ` first

Comment: You're not assigning to `d['foo']`. You're assigning to `d['foo']['bar']`, which requires that `d['foo']` already exists. Just as assigning to `e['bar']` requires that `e` exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have, at least, two options:

1. Create nested dictionaries in order:

```
d = {}
d['foo'] = {}
d['foo']['bar'] = 1
```

2. Use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), passing the default factory as dict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)
d['foo']['bar'] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks all. I figured it was something like that.  I do most of my scripting in Perl, where you can just do things like that on the fly.  It's great.

Comment: #2 is such a nice lifehack. Glad i found this.

Comment: Note: it only works for 1 level of nesting.

Answer (score 0):

you need to assign  d['key'] to be a dictionary first

```
d['a']={}
d['a']['b']= value
```