# How can you select a specific dictionary by id in order to update its contents(Python)?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
cont = {}
n = int(input("Insert the number of transactions:"))

if n == 0:
    print("Going to the next option")
else:
    for i in range(0, n):
        tranz = input("Insert the id of the transaction: ")
        ziua = input("Insert the day: ")
        suma = input("Insert the amount: ")
        tipul = input("Insert the type(int/out): ")
        tranz_key = tranz[0]
        cont[tranz] = {"day": ziua, "amount": suma, "type": tipul}



k = input("Do you wish to update something?(Yes/No): ")


if k == 'No':
    print("Going to the next option")
else:
    y = input("Insert a new day:")
    if len(y) != 0:
        cont[tranz].update({"day": y})
    z = input("Insert a new amount:")
    if len(z) != 0:
        z = int(z)
        cont[tranz].update({"amount": z})
    w = input("Insert a new type(in/out):")
    if len(w) != 0:
        cont[tranz].update({"type": w})
```

Hello, I have to create a program that is able to add a transaction with the following details: `day`, `sum`, and `type`. I don't know how many transactions there will be so I found a code that I adapted to match my needs. In the last part of my code I want to try to update a specific dictionary (for example, if the user wants to modify the amount in a transaction with the id of 1, I should select that specific dictionary and modify it). I am a beginner in Python, but I have some knowledge regarding programming overall. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add new keys to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/how-can-i-add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `cont` is already a dictionary, you just have to replicate the same behaviour for the other dictionaries.

So for example, after the user input the program its transaction id (in `tranz`) and the sum in `z`, you could do something like this to edit only the sum:

```py
cont[tranz][amount] = z
```

Be aware that this is going to work only if you already set `cont[tranz]` as a `dict` (you do it already in your `range(0, n)` cycle)