# How to add all the values to a dictionary using for loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have the keys as key1= [(0,0,0), (0,0,1),(1,0,0), (0,1,0)]

```py
  for x1,x2,x3 in key1:
        
        summat= #some expression that has new value for each keys
        tempDict ={(x1,x2,x3): summat}
  print(tempDict)
```

It only prints the last value(0,1,0) and the summat of last value but I want to store all the values of summat for all the value of keys

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can run your code and see what's wrong. Right now it's quite unclear what you have in mind and what's going wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add new keys to a dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/how-can-i-add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: Do you want to add the values of the dictionary together?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing what you have into a dictionary comprehension:

`tempDict = {key: summat(key) for key in key1}`

This is the equivalent to:

```
tempDict = {}
for key in key1:
   tempDict.update({key: summat(key)}
```

Your code will overwrite the value of tempDict each iteration, so at the end you'll only see the last value.