# How to insert one dict into another?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict `a = {'zgd': 0, 'zjd: 748'}` and another dict `b = {'jds': 748, 'jdl': 100}`

How can I combine `b` into `a` with another key, `'gzbx'`, like:

`{'zgd': 0, 'zjd': 748, 'gzbx': {'jds': 748, 'jdl': 100}}`?

I'd like the simplest Python code to complete it.

Comment: Have you looked into using the update method in the dictionary class? Here is an example usage: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_update.asp

Comment: @tschmitz You don't need the `update` method for what the OP wants. A simple assignment to the specified key will do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add new keys to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/how-can-i-add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a['gzbx'] = b
```

Here's a link to python's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), which should be helpful for basic syntax.